# Mean of Piecewise function resting on IID random variables

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose IID random variables $X_t \sim X$ with support on $[0,1]$ and continuous CDF $F(\cdot)$.

I wish to compute the expected value (mean) of the a piecewise function with form
$$
\Phi (x,\mu) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
   \beta x & \quad \text{if $x < \mu$}\\
   (1-\beta) + \beta x & \quad \text{if $x \geq \mu$}\\
  \end{array} \right.
$$
where $\beta \in [0,1]$ and $\mu$ at time $t$ is given by

$$
\mu_t = \frac{1}{t} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{t} Y_i,$$
with $Y_1 = X_1$ and $Y_t = \Phi(X_t, \mu_{t-1}) \quad \forall t >1$.

How can I compute $\mathbb{E}[\Phi (X,\mu^*)]$ for $\mu^*$ (a specific value of $\mu$) ?

$$
\mathbb{E}[\Phi (X,\mu^*)] = \mathbb{E}[(\beta X_t) \mathbf{1}\{X_t<\mu^*\} + (\beta X_t+1-\beta)\mathbf{1}\{X_t\geq \mu^*\}]
= .... ?
$$

Comment: I don't see how your $\Phi(x,\mu)$ is continuous: at $x=\mu$ one has $\Phi\to \beta\mu$ from the left and $\Phi\to (1-\beta)+\beta\mu$ from the right. These only match if $\beta=1$, which is surely not your intention. Did you want your second function to linearly interpolate $f(\mu)$ and $1$?

Comment: You haven't defined the $\mu_k$ used when defining $Y_k$. Is it $\mu_k=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k Y_k$ and $\mu=\mu_t$?

Comment: My bad @Semiclassical : $\mu_t = \frac{1}{t} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{t}Y_t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\Phi (X,\mu^*)] &= \mathbb{E}[(\beta X_t) \mathbf{1}\{X_t<\mu^*\} + (\beta X_t+1-\beta)\mathbf{1}\{X_t\geq \mu^*\}]\\
 &= \mathbb{E}[ (\beta X_t) \mathbf{1}\{X_t<\mu^*\} +  (\beta X_t) \mathbf{1}\{X_t\geq \mu^*\} + (1-\beta) \mathbf{1}\{X_t\geq \mu^*\}]\\
&= \beta \mathbb{E}[X] + (1-\beta)\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}\{X_t\geq \mu^*\}]\\
&= \beta \mathbb{E}[X] + (1-\beta) \mathbf{P}(X_t\geq \mu^*)
\end{align}

Can I write $\mathbf{P}(X_t\geq \mu^*) = \overline{F}(\mu)$ ?